# Reading hex numbers as 2 digits per char from bin file -c++

Tags: c++, hex, binaryfiles, bitset

I am writing a c++ program to read a bin file.The binary file has the following sample contents.

```
10 00 01 02 20 03 04 40 50 .....
```

The problem here is by using normal read from bin file the byte 10 ,40, 50 are read correctly. But in case of 00, 01, 02 03.... they are read as 0, 1, 2 ,3 respectively.

But i want the individual bytes 00 01 02 03 etc also to be read as **00 01 02 03 etc **. The reason being, i am trying to convert the values to binary. so i want to get the binary equivalent of **"10 00 01 02"** which is **10000000000000000000100000010**. But because the the contents are being interpreted as ***10012***, i get ***10000000000010010*** as the result. Please do help me in solving this. Sorry if the content is too lengthy. Thanks in advance.

I used the following code. // cut shorted for simplicity

```
fstream fp;
fp.open(binFile, ios::binary | ios::in);
char * buffer = new char[4];
// read data as a block:
fp.read(buffer, 4);
// copied the contents of buffer[] to a string str
stringstream ss;
for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
{
    ss << std::hex << unsigned(*it);
}
ss >> intvalue; // stores the converted hex value 
string binstring = bitset<32>(intvalue).to_string();
cout<<binstring // produces wrong value.
```

Comment: What is `temp`? What is `hex`? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Look at <iomanip> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip  (setfill)

Comment: How on earth does `00 01 02 03` lead you to "wanting" to get the binary equivalent of `10 00 01 02` ?? And is that first line hex octets from a dump of you "bin" file, or are the actual ascii *characters* ? Not going ot sugarcoat it; your post isn't clear.

Comment: in memory 01 and 1 are the same number, your problem is not at read time but when you print it wanting 2 digits in hexa no ?

Comment: `they are read as 0, 1, 2 ,3` Is `1` not equal to `01` ?

Comment: Edit 1: i have edited the post.( temp then) now str is the string read from file. and hex is std::hex which is used to convert string to hexadecimal . Edit 2:  what i meant is the bytes 00 01 02 03 in the file should be read as such instead of being read as 0 1 2 and 3. and as an example i said i want the binary equivalent of 10 00 01 02. but i get the binary equivalent of 10 0 1 2

Comment: There is no difference between `01` and `1`. Only how you choose to print it (with or without leading zero)

Comment: Just bit shift it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting from single bytes to biger types of integers is typically done using bitshifts.

```
unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char[4];
fp.read(buffer, 4);
uint32_t result =  buffer[0] << 24 | buffer[1] << 16 | buffer[2] << 8 | buffer[3];
```

If you want to have a *string* object (*not* a number) with the hexadecimal *representation* of the number with leading zeros filled up to 8 characters of hexadecimal representation, you can indeed use `<<` overloaded operator with some `iomanip` to print it. You have to use hex and print it with leading zeros. You have to also cast to an integer, because characters are printed like characters, not like numbers.

```
std::stringstream ss;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(buffer[i]);
}
std::string str(ss.str);
```

or

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss  << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << result;
std::string str(ss.str);
```

If you want to have a string object with the representation of the number in base 2 including with leading zeros you can indeed use `bitset` `to_string()`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   std::cout << bitset<8>(buffer[i]).to_string();
}
```

or again use the `result` from above:

```
std::cout << bitset<32>(result).to_string();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. +1 for the neat and clear explanation. Unable to give +1 in the post. Thanks